# Determine if subdirectory is on a mounted file system with Python

Tags: python, path

In this path, the directory 'foo' is mounted on an external file system.  The directory 'bar' is a subdirectory of 'foo'.

```
'/Volumes/foo/bar'
```

Using `os.path.ismount('/Volumes/foo')`, I can determine correctly that 'foo' is indeed an external mount.  However, using `os.path.ismount('/Volumes/foo/bar')` on 'bar' determines correctly that it is NOT mounted externally.

So, my question is, how can I correctly determine that 'bar' is a subdirectory of an externally mounted file system?  I need to be able to determine the same about many directories of varying depth.  Any clues would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Return True if pathname path is a mount **point**

emphasis mine. A subdirectory of a mount pointed directory is on a mount drive, but not a mount "point".

> how can I correctly determine that 'bar' is a subdirectory of an externally mounted file system?

In this case, I would iterate through the parent hierarchy until I reach the root, or I hit a mount-point. Whichever comes first.

Assuming a Unix type filesystem:

```
def is_on_mount(path):
  while True:
    if path == os.path.dirname(path):
      # we've hit the root dir
      return False
    elif os.path.ismount(path):
      return True
    path = os.path.dirname(path)

path = '/mount/one/two/three'
is_on_mount(path)
```

Comment: This was close but actually it doesn't work because `os.path.dirname('/mount/one/two/three')` is actually `/mount/one/two/three` so the function fails on line 3

Comment: Hmmm that shouldn't be the case. Can you copy + paste the code again because I immediately made an edit one min after posting. The dirname of that should not be the same.

Comment: Fails on Windows, eg if `path=r'C:\x'` -> `False`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import subprocess


def is_on_mounted_volume(path):
    try:
        df = subprocess.check_output(['df', path]).split('\n')
        mountpoint = df[1].split()[-1][0]
        return os.path.ismount(mountpoint)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
```

Comment: That won't work in the case of `/Volumes/foo/bar/baz`

Comment: Actually, it subprocess crashes if the subdirectory doesn't exist

Comment: Maybe you want to write something about your solution, not just paste code. Copypasting code is not a good behaviour to encourage.